# Seeking Powershell Function to Check if multiple Folders Exist Before moving files

Tags: powershell, automation, move, file-storage, organizer

**The Back Story:** I back up my android apps before installing updates to a single folder on my NAS. I want to use a Windows machine that is mapped to this folder to run a powershell script daily if not weekly which I know how to do.

**The Goal:** Is to move the files by partial name (Ex: Adobe Acrobat * & Adobe Scan *) into a folder structure that is predefined using the company name and then inside that folder the product. (EX: \Adobe\Acrobat\ & \Adobe\Scan)

So far I have:

```
$Adobe = "Z:\APK\Adobe\" #Set Path For Adobe Folder


#Adobe Products
If (!(test-path $Adobe)) #Check if Adobe Folder Does Not Exist
{ 
    #If Does Not Exist Create Folder
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Adobe 
}
#Move Anything matching "Adobe" in its name to the $Adobe folder
Move-Item Z:\Adobe* $Adobe -Force
```

**The Problem:**

1. As you can see in my code I am putting everything with Adobe* into the Adobe folder but can't figure out how to use whitespaces to grab the product name from the above examples.
2. There has to be an easier way than writing a test path for each folder as there is over 100 apps and I would generally like to store more from family and friends so you can see how that will grow. So I would like to have a function do the work of checking all folders in a loop and if they do not exist have it create that structure. To make it easier we can use the above example of two Adobe products.

Disclaimer: If I ever release the code it will be on Github and open source with Credits built into my script but I intend to use this for personal use and 0 Commercial gain

Comment: Well, where are the *products* / applications stored? There has to be a `Get-ChildItem` somewhere in here to get the apps lol

Comment: The Applications are stored the Root Folder: Z:\ but I want them organized in folders. The code above works but I have to create lines of code for every single APK file . However it does not work for anything with a similar name.. So the above example will not work because Adobe Scan and Adobe Acrobat will get stored in the Adobe folder instead of the Adobe\Scan and Adobe\Acrobat folders further requiring I manually move the files

So no Get-ChildItem required

Comment: If the files always follow the same format, i.e.: "Company Product.apk" this is pretty easy to do and no function is required. And as Abraham pointed out, `Get-ChildItem` is required for this script.

Comment: But I would have to check if the folder exists wouldn't I? and if it does not exist I would have to have the script create it if I am correct?

P.s. I am confused isn't Get-ChildItem used to display a list of the matching items? Could I use the output to move the files into respective folders and sub folders?

Comment: My assumptions were just as good as Santiagos as well.

Comment: I tried this code in a powershell and did not get a return:  Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\* -Include *Hilton Honors*

but I get a return list of all the names matching the following: Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\* -Include *GoPro* which includes Go pro and GoPro Quik ...this would move both of these products into one folder called GoPro but I wanted to Move these into K:\GoPro\GoPro\ and K:\GoPro\Quik\

Comment: It might just be the way I am explaining it. Sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like this

```
$path = 'C:\temp\powershell\apk_organizer\apk'
$apkFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.apk -File

$apkFiles | ForEach-Object {
    # Get vendor and product strings
    $vendor, $product, $null = $_.BaseName -split ' '

    # Generate the new path
    $newPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($path, $vendor, $product) 
    # or 
    # $newPath = Join-Path $path (Join-Path $vendor $product)

    # Create new path if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path $newPath)){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $newPath | Out-Null
    }

    # Move file to new path (Remove -WhatIf after testing)
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Verbose -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: I never knew you could assign variables like that. Fancy fancy!(: Guess its similar to the `-f` formatting.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, yes it is very handy sometimes.  I learned that from mklement0 :).  Check out [Assigning multiple variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.1#assigning-multiple-variables)

Comment: Man, I've learned so much from that guy haha refer to him as *Powershell Pops*. Gonna make that name stick  lol. Gonna check out the link now, thanks man!

Comment: It created the folder structure and I see a problem I didn't see before. The Among Us game does not have the Vendor Name first so it creates K:\Among\Us as the structure but also doesn't move the file. I am going to have to scratch this project as is and rethink it due to lack of standardization in the naming scheme.

I might have to code this manually the long way. any idea of how I can Move-Item for something that matchs "Among Us" ?

Using the example I have doesn't exactly match "Among Us" but matches anything with "Among"

Comment: EX
`$AmongUs = "Z:\Among Us\"
Move-Item Z:\Among* $AmongUs -Force `

Comment: It should move the file if you remove the `-WhatIf` switch at the end of the last line like the comment says, but I agree, you need to standardize your naming conventions or add more conditions to your code that target all the non-standard items.

Comment: I found a temporary solution. I can still use the script above I just have to add a ` charter between spaces so I can match the exact name of the file before the version numbers.

Still alot of lines of code but I will revisit it once I have it working 100%

Answer (score 0):

To get the ball rolling so others may comment as well, i'll kick it off. Hopefully I understood you right so bear with me. Say we have all these apps you're trying to move in location A. *Assuming* that the app names have a space seperated by product ( `Adobe` ), then version ( `Acrobat` ) we can take an approach of splitting the names, by product and version.

```
$Where_My_Apps_Are = "E:\My\Apps\Location"
$Where_I_want_Them_To_Be = "D:\My\Apps\Destination"

$My_Apps = Get-ChildItem -Path $Where_My_Apps_Are -Filter "Adobe*" -File -Recurse 
    foreach ($App in $My_Apps) {
        
        $Name_Split = $App.BaseName.Split(' ')
        $App_NameFolder = Join-Path -Path $Where_I_want_Them_To_Be -ChildPath $Name_Split[0]
        $App_Version    = Join-Path -Path $App_NameFolder -ChildPath $Name_Split[1]

        $App_Name_Test = Test-Path -Path $App_NameFolder
        $App_Version_Test = Test-Path -Path $App_Version
            if ($App_Name_Test -eq $false) {

                New-Item $App_NameFolder -ItemType Directory

                    if ($App_Version_Test -eq $false) {

                        New-Item $App_Version -ItemType Directory
                        Move-Item $App.FullName -Destination $App_Version

                    }
                    else {

                        Move-Item $App.FullName -Destination $App_Version

                }
            }
            elseif ($App_Version_Test -eq $false) {

                New-Item $App_Version_Test -ItemType Directory
                Move-Item $App.FullName -Destination $App_Version

            }
            else {

                Move-Item $App.FullName -Destination $App_Version

            }
    }
```

See, the problem with this, is i'm assuming all applications will be product, then version format seperated by a space. We can collect all related apps into a variable ( `$My_Apps` ), split the name, test against each section of the name, create a folder if not there, move the item into the directory, or just move the item (app) into the directory if directory is there.

Probably best if you turn this into a function and pass it a filter variable to search for specific apps just for the convenienve of manual movement, but you can also have it do it for all apps it finds; *assuming they're all in the format mentioned above*.

Please note: just wanted to point readers in the right direction ( *if i understood this correctly* ) so they can give you a better answer.

Comment: Hopefully I didn't overlook something (*which I believe I may have). Just on a time crunch at the moment. Someone much smarter than me should be able to narrow this down:)

Comment: I will try this code but here is two screenshots of the apk files and the folder structure for Adobe. I would like to automate the manual process of moving each adobe product into its own folder and do the same thing for other apk files as well

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qpylmOLMHUK0C83ivMcbU2sTlT93c4wE?usp=sharing

Comment: @memdump, did the code not work? Theoretically it does what you're asking for given the few *gotcha issues* with the names.

Comment: The Script successfully moved the "Adobe Acrobat 21.4.0.17702_1921417702.apk" into \Adobe\Acrobat\ folder but the others that were similar just moved the APK into the Adobe folder with just the name of the product with no extension... I had this happen in my script above before. I'm going to see if I can figure this out then I have to figure out how to turn this into a function to run it on all the files not just Adobe apk files. You got me closer for sure.

Comment: Similar how? Did the version change? Meaning, was there another app named "Adobe Distiller"?

Comment: "Adobe Capture 4.1 (732)_40001711.apk was moved into K:\APK\Adobe\ with the file name "Capture" instead of it being a folder named Capture and "Adobe Capture 4.1 (732)_40001711.apk" inside of that folder.

P.S. I know its a file instead of a folder because its the same size as before the move.

Comment: So, yes. There was another app with a different version. I suggest changing the last `elseif` to the following: `if ($App_Name_Test -eq $true -and $App_Version_Test -eq $false) {`. Also, it'll always be a file as long as the parameter `-File` is specified.